# Localization morphism as epimorphism of sprectra

Tags: algebraic-geometry

The category of affine schemes is equivalent to the opposite category of commutative rings, because a morphism $f:\operatorname{Spec} A\to \operatorname{Spec} B$ corresponds to a morphism $g:B\to A$.

Therefore, a surjective morphism $g:B\to A$ corresponds to an injective morphism $f:\operatorname{Spec} A\to \operatorname{Spec} B$. We can easily check in this case that $g$ induces a bijection between the prime ideals of $A$ and the prime ideals of $B$ that contain $\ker g$.

However, the localization of $A$ at one of its prime ideals $P$ is often an injective ring morphism $i:A\to A_P$. Then it should correspond to a surjective morphism $f:\operatorname{Spec} A_P\to \operatorname{Spec} A$. But that does not seem correct, because $i$ induces a bijection between Spec $A_P$ and the prime ideals of $A$ contained in $P$.

Then are affine schemes really equivalent to the opposite category of commutative rings? Or does the injective localization only induce an epimorphism of spectra, which might not be surjective?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surjections and injections are not "categorical" notions, so yes, "epimorphic" is not "surjective". This is also true for rings, e.g. any localization map is epimorphic. Now, it is true that a monomorphism of rings is an injection, e.g. because the forgetful functor $\operatorname{Ring} \to \operatorname{Set}$ is left-exact, but the corresponding epimorphism of affine schemes is not surjective as a map of sets.